# Find all keys inside array inside object of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object (i can not change it, it cames from an outside webservice) and I want to get all the ids, (structure inside data may change)

```
data: {
    consoles:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ],
    games:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ],
    accesories:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ]    
}
```

I was trying to get all the keys of the object with Object.keys(data) and after that do a for to try to print it

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
    console.log(keys[j]);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.keys[j].length; i++){
        console.log(data.keys[j].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `productsKeys` defined?

Comment: Sorry its a typping mistake, productsKeys is keys

Comment: What are your results

Comment: `data.keys[j]` is not valid javascript (if you want to use keys[j] as the actual key), you need to do `data[keys[j]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:-

```
var productsKeys = Object.keys(data);
for(var j = 0; j < productsKeys.length; j++){     
  for(var i = 0; i < data[productsKeys[j]].length; i++){         
     console.log(data[productsKeys[j]][i].id)
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/38Lmgu7h/3/)

Comment: Thanks Learner, this fix my first idea, works great !

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the `data.keys[j]` with:

```
data[keys[j]]
```

So this gives you with:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data);
for(var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++){
    console.log(keys[j]);
    for(var i = 0; i < data.keys[j].length; i++){
        console.log(data[keys[j]].id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working, i need to pass 'i' iteration to the result of the second loop

Answer (score 0):

here is what my try is how can you achieve this

```js
data = {
    consoles:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ],
    games:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ],
    accesories:[
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        },
        {
            name:'',
            id:''
        }
    ]    
}
  

  
$.each(data,function(key,val){
   $.each(data[key],function(k,v){
      $.each(v,function(kf,vf){
           console.log(kf + "---->" + vf); 
      }); 
   });
});
```

Comment: @gil13 welcom dude please accept as answer if you got your needed . or upvote

Comment: Not enough reputation to give you an upvote, and works better (in performance) native javascript solution, sorry Himesh.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<data.consoles.length;i++){
console.log( data.consoles[i].id);
}

for(var i=0; i<data.games.length;i++){
console.log( data.games[i].id);
}

for(var i=0; i<data.accessories.length;i++){
console.log( data.accessories[i].id);
}
```

If consoles,games,accessories arrays have laways the same length we can use only one `for`.

Comment: Thanks but should be dynamic, games, consoles etc may change names